# python sys library command prompt

Tags: python, command-line-interface, interactive

I am trying out the sys library in python. In command prompt I am using this.

```
>>>import sys
>>>sys.ps1 ='$'
#my own input 'print 'test print''
$print 'test print'
test print
```

That worked in CLI, however, when I tried to do it in a python file and run it in CLI ( `python file.py` did not return anything.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
sys.ps1= '$'
```

Am I missing anything in the file?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You just changed the ">>>" to "$" in your first example, it only works in interactive mode.

Comment: @Jacob so there is no way to do that in a file? I am learning python from the documentation, and i came across this and wanted to test it out that is it.

Comment: You want to start python in interactive mode with a different prompt? `python -i -c "import sys; sys.ps1='$'"` will do that.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to rephrase your question and explicitly state your goal. It sounds like Eric has answered your question, but it could help others in the future who have your problem if it is stated more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do?  sys.ps1 will just set the prompt for the python interpreter, so as soon as it exits it's effect is gone again.  When running a file, there is no command-line.

If you want to see this have an effect, try running this with `python -i file.py` - this will run the command, and then drop you into the interactive shell, which should have PS1 set to `$` now